# jQuery background color changed, hover background-color not working

Tags: jquery, css, colors, background

So I've run into this problem today.
I have setup a couple of div's, with a background color (we'll call it 'color #1') assigned trough css, trough a class name, let's say '.color', and after that, I've made each div change its background color to a specific one ('color #2'), on hover, also trough css.

The problem is:
I've made a jquery script in which I want to change the general backgroundcolor ('color #1') into another (color #3), and that works, but the hover function is now broken, because the divs do not change to color#2 on hover.
Anyone has any idea why? Is there any incompatibility between the css file and jquery?
I have no live example for this one, but if you could provide a solution, that'd be great.

Comment: Demonstrate it in fiddle or post your code here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery `hover()` to get rid of this problem.

```
<div id="test">test</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="changecolor"/>


$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#test").css("background-color","red");
});
$("#test").hover(function(){
  $("#test").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xb5AP/7/)

Comment: That's great, thanks, but the thing is I don't want to clutch my js file with like over 10 codes of line, just for trying to change one background color commune for all divs. I just want my jquery .css command not to overwrite the hovers in the css script. If I have no solution to this, yours might be the only one :S

Comment: But why does jquery behave like that, cant i just setup priority?

Comment: priority? i dont know the exact behaviour of that.. please tick the answer if this helped you

Comment: I can use your solution, but that means in need to write your code 12 times, and i really want to keep it short as possible.

Comment: you can give class names to wanted tags. Then you can do it with single line

Comment: I've made some research and I've figured it out. I had to add '!important' on my css hover lines. :D